# Strongest Encryption and Hashing Algorithms Today

Tags: security, encryption, hashing

Basically, I want to know what the strongest (hardest to break) encryption algorithm today is.  The same goes for the hashing algorithm.  Let's say I pick a super-strong password too (bonus: how long is a secure password with the encryption algorithm?), for the encryption algorithm part.  I don't care how long it takes, or whether it is the "standard" of today (ex.: I've heard that AES is the "standard", but that it is not the most secure algorithm out there), just as long as it is impenetrable.

**UPDATE:** I realize this is a very general question, so let me narrow it a bit.  Let's say that I am trying to securely correspond with someone, or that I just don't want anyone to decipher my text, and I want it to be as secure as is currently humanly possible. What type of encryption algorithm should I look at, what key size, what bit size, and what specific algorithm should I use? Same goes for hashing.

**UPDATE:** To narrow it down more, let's say that the 'Bob' of this case has a private key that only he knows. Let's say that everyone in the world was given a copy of the encrypted message, but only 'Bob' should be able to decrypt it.

(I realize this might be starting to sound shady, but this is all a hypothetical situation.)

Comment: This question is rather broad, and can vary depending on what you are using the encryption for. What are you encrypting? What are you using to do so? Often times the encryption algorithm itself isn't the weakest point, but rather the way it is implemented. Don't assume that because you're using a 4096-bit RSA key that the encryption as a whole is going to be impenetrable.

Comment: VTC: This is a product list request, which is considered off-topic.  It will age and become useless.  Here's a good list to get you going: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Cryptography

Comment: @techie007 Won't everything about computers eventually age and become useless (in what scenario of the progression of the human race does technology remain stagnant indefinitely?)? The link doesn't provide a useful comparison.

Comment: @user244358: Does everyone in the world have the corresponding public key and know that it belongs to Bob?

Comment: Let's say yes, it does.

Comment: Question asks about ALGORITHM not a program.

Answer (score 2):

The question is really impossible to answer. There is no universal concept of algorithmic "strength". Strength is, essentially, resistance to an attack. Because there are different categories of attacks, strength depends on which attacks you need to resist. There is no limit to how strong you can make an encryption or hashing algorithm if you have no requirements. The trick is finding the strongest (or a sufficiently strong) algorithm that meets particular requirements.

There are some applications where particular "attacks" are irrelevant because they don't affect the requirements. For example, there might be a hashing algorithm that's very, very strong against everything against length extension attacks. This might make it the strongest algorithm for an application where length extension attacks don't matter (such as signing hashes) but wholly unsuitable for one where they do (such as API keys).

Also, there are completely different categories of encryption algorithms with drastically different properties. For example, there are symmetric and asymmetric encryption algorithms.

**Update 1**: You're still not giving us the most basic information. For encryption to work, there should be something the intended recipient has or knows that nobody else knows or has that allows them, and only them, to decrypt the message. Without any clue of what that might be, there's no way to even know what class of algorithms to be looking at. If there are no requirements, the answer is probably a one time pad, though that's almost always entirely impractical.

**Update 2**: With your additional information, [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) with [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) is the obvious choice.

Comment: I realize this is very general, so I've tried to narrow it down. Please check the update/edit.

Comment: That doesn't help at all, since you haven't listed any requirements or a threat model. For example, can you pre-arrange a key with that person? If not, what does the recipient have that nobody else has that will allow them and only them to read the correspondence?

Comment: It is now updated.

Comment: Wasn't RSA broken in WWII? Also, these two algorithms vs bcrypt (the other answer)?

Comment: In addition, vs AES. Sorry to be a pain, but I am curious to as why you chose these two.

Comment: RSA didn't exist until at least the late 1960s and bcrypt is not an encryption algorithm. AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm. (Though it could be used as the bulk encryption algorithm.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was thinking of Enigma, but I still thought RSA was out of date.  What is the difference between a symmetric or asymmetric encryption algorithm?

Comment: A symmetric encryption algorithm requires the two parties to have a shared secret, an asymmetric algorithm does not.

Comment: Doesn't my situation allow for that?

Comment: I suppose theoretically so, but then the private key would be entirely superfluous and we would need some other way to specify Bob as the recipient. That's why I asked you how we were going to do that.

Comment: Hmmm... Say, in a different situation, I could use symmetric encryption, then... AES vs RSA?

Comment: It usually doesn't get framed that way because even if you use RSA, you typically still need a symmetric algorithm for the "bulk encryption".

Answer (score 1):

There is such thing as [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). The main point that it is VERY SLOW. So, briefly - it will take years for hacker to crack it because you can make it to calculate your hash in 1 second. Not long time for one user for single authentication procedure. But for hacker 1 second is A LOT because he has to try millions of combinations. In comparison - SHA-1 (for example) calculates you cache for milliseconds. Same thins for hacker - it will be very convenient for him to brute force your password. So, I recommend [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

**EDIT** I want to greatly admit comment of @Huskehn. It is very important how it is implemented. Security includes many aspects, not just choosing strongest hashing algorithm.

Comment: bcrypt is based on Blowfish. I see that it makes a number of improvements.

1) What key size do you recommend?
2) As far as hashes go...?

Comment: What bit-size is recommended?

Comment: Key length will affect security. By increasing key length you making it harder to crack it. Now, it is really up to you because it greatly depends on your setup and what are you doing. Take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_622705&feature=iv&src_vid=3QnD2c4Xovk&v=YEBfamv-_do) and other videos of this author. It gives great and SIMPLE explanation of encryption and will give you a lot of data.

Comment: I've seen that video before, but thanks, it was useful, though it doesn't help me solve my problem.